Using the Steam Deck as a PS5 controller
I recently made the switch from my PS5 to the Steam Deck, and I've gotten very used to having the paddles and controller layout of the Deck. However, I haven't been able to get great performance on some of my favorite games, and I'm thinking about switching back to the PS5 for some of those.
One of the reasons I switched was because of the discomfort the DualSense controllers brought, whereas the Deck's controller layout feels much more natural and feels better in my hands.
Is there some way I can use the Steam Deck as a controller for the Playstation?
Some things I've tried:

Using Chiaki: Isn't very reliable, causes lag, etc.
Using the Steam version of DualSenseX: Isn't supported on Steam Deck

Things I'm still looking into:
My original thoughts were to maybe use a wired controller emulator (via USB cable), and build a simple desktop app that can be launched in Gaming Mode to control the Playstation. However, I've had a bit of trouble finding a software that will work well for this. I'm still searching for accessibility-based apps that I can use to emulate a DualSense controller.
